# Docker Compose: Set Up two compose files for developpement and deployement in the same Repository

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Hi Stackoverflow Community,

I would like to know, if there any way to set up 2 docker-compose files in the same repository, one for production and the other for development, which we can run them in the same server at the same time.

Indeed, We use the production file for the client & the development one for develop new features, **and as I've said, they must be working on the same time**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two different files.

- docker-compose.prod.yml
- docker-compose.dev.yml

Use the -f flag specifies the file to use.

```sh
Options:
  -f, --file FILE             Specify an alternate compose file
                              (default: docker-compose.yml)
```

Try `docker-compose --help` for more info.

Comment: Worth mentioning: 1) It is best to have the "default" one named `docker-compose.yml`, and 2) you can use the `COMPOSE_FILE` environment variable to specify the file name in any environment where it should not be the default.